# How to calculate overall correlation from a correlation matrix with weighted variables?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

If I have a pearson correlation matrix, I believe I can take a mean of all the individual pairwise correlations to get an overall correlation for the matrix.

But how do I calculate an overall correlation for a matrix if each variable (not observations which were used to generate the correlation matrix) has a different weight, eg given by a vector v?

As an example with 3 variables A, B, and C, and the pairwise pearson correlations are:

```
A, B : .73
B, C : .67
A, C : .62
A, A : 1
etc
```

with a vector of weights A, B, and C of [.1 .1 .8].

Examples I have found discuss either using covariance matrices, or use a correlation matrix but with weighted data points to produce each pairwise correlation, not weighted on the level of the variable.

I am using Numpy to calculate the correlation matrix. Thanks.